# How to get thread ID from thread handle in windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

Is there a better and cheaper way to get the thread ID from thread's handle,
Or the only way is to snap all the process threads.

I want to do on NT 3.1 or more
GetThreadID is for Vista

Thanks.

Comment: Really?  NT 3.1 is over 20 years old, and you still need to support it?

Comment: No I want this on XP (NT 3.1 or more...) :)

Comment: I found a solution in josh poley's given link, NtQueryInformationThread provides information about thread and also include thread unique identifiers(TID , PID), but it may change on diffrent releases of windows, but for sure its accessible in XP and for higher versions you can use GetThreadID.

Comment: How did you end up with the thread handle and not the thread ID?

Comment: Windows XP is NT 5.1, not 3.1.

Comment: I said 3.1 and **MORE**.... ahh